# ContentObserver with URI doesnt work for Contacts in API Level 16

Tags: uri, android-4.2-jelly-bean, contentobserver

I am trying following code:

```
private class NativeContentObserver extends ContentObserver  {
      public NativeContentObserver() {
         super(null);
      }

      @Override
      public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
         super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
         Log.i(TAG, "uri is "+uri);
}

{
NativeContentObserver contentObserver = new NativeContentObserver();
mContext.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
           ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, contentObserver);
}
```

When I run this code and edit a contact, I see

uri is content://com.android.contacts

WHY I am not getting the ID of individual contact in URI? If I try SMS observer, I do get correct URI which contains ID there.
Anything I am missing here? This is on Samsung S3 handset.

Comment: Did you get solution for the same ? I am also getting the same URL .

Answer (score 0):

most probably because provideres update method calls notifyChange(uri) with complete URI, instead of filtered one.  if this is the case, that means ContactsContract.Contacts has been deprecated. search for alternatives